# How do I check for a specific character after a user inputed a string?

Tags: c

I am a new developer to C and I am trying to make a password detector and I am trying to code something that reads the users password and checks if it has a "!" in it. Yet, I cant seem to get it to work. the output of "int special" always equals 0.
The code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    // check for special characters
    // check for length of password
    char password[30];
    int length;
    int len = 15;

    printf("Dear user please enter a password:\n ");
    scanf_s("%s", &password, 30);

    length = strlen(password);
    if (length < len) {
        printf("invalid password (password must be 15 - 30 characters)");
        exit();
    }

    int special = 0;
    if (strchr(password, "!") != NULL)
    {
        special = 1;
    }
    printf("%d", special);
}
```

Comment: Typo here: `scanf_s("%s", &password, 30);`, you do not need the `&`.

Comment: Just a hint for future questions: It's always appreciated if example input and corresponding output are included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea of the program is correct, but a couple of fixes are needed to make it work and standard compliant:

- The typical signature for the main function, using no parameters, is `int main(void)`. See the C standard document for more information.
- Include `stdlib.h` for the `exit(..)` function. This function needs an argument, and since it is used to exit with failure, the best choice is `EXIT_FAILURE` as defined in `stdlib.h`. Since `exit(..)` is called in the main function, another option is to simply return `EXIT_FAILURE`.
- The `scanf_s` function is a bit of a special case: `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` needs to be defined as the integer constant `1` before `stdio.h` is included. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more information. Note that providing an implementation for this function is *optional* in C, so it is not the best choice for portability. Here, `fgets` is a better alternative.
- The function `scanf_s` needs a `char` array to write to and `password` has exactly that type. Therefore, the "address of" operator (`&`) shouldn't be used here.
- Then function `strchr` needs a `char` argument (`'!'`), not a string literal (`"!"`). See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) for the exact function prototype.

The code will all fixes applied:

```c
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    // check for special characters
    // check for length of password
    char password[30];
    int length;
    int len = 15;

    printf("Dear user please enter a password:\n");
    scanf_s("%s", password, 30);

    length = strlen(password);
    if (length < len) {
        printf("invalid password (password must be 15 - 30 characters)\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int special = 0;
    if (strchr(password, '!') != NULL)
    {
        special = 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", special);
}
```

A few additional suggestions:

- Use a macro for the constant length to give it a name, and to define it once and reuse it multiple times.
- Use the `size_t` type for lengths. This is also the type that is returned by `strlen`.
- Declare variables as close as possible to where these are first used.
- Store the result of `strchr` directly into a boolean value. To use the `bool` type, include `stdbool.h`.

The improved code:

```c
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PASSWORD_LENGTH_MAX 30U

int main(void) {
    char password[PASSWORD_LENGTH_MAX];

    printf("Dear user please enter a password:\n");
    scanf_s("%s", password, PASSWORD_LENGTH_MAX);

    size_t length_min = 15U;
    size_t length = strlen(password);
    if (length < length_min) {
        printf("Invalid password (password must be 15 - 30 characters)\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    bool contains_special_character = strchr(password, '!');
    printf("%d\n", contains_special_character);
}
```